# How to read Images from excel and store them in database using laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]I am using **Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class** plugin ,I want to store images and product details through Excel sheet.

How can I **upload** images .excel data  ?

**please help me...**

> ProductController.php

```
public function excelupload()
    {

        if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
            $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            })->get();
            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    dd($value);
                    $insert[] = ['product_name' => $value->product_name, 'cataloge_number' => $value->cataloge_number, 'cas_number' => $value->cas_number, 'product_image' => $value->product_image, 'chemical_name' => $value->chemical_name , 'synonyms' => $value->synonyms , 'molecular_formula' => $value->molecular_formula, 'molecular_mass' => $value->molecular_mass ,'product_stock' => $value->product_stock];
                }
                if(!empty($insert)){

                    DB::table('products')->insert($insert);

                   return redirect('admin/product')->with('message', 'New Product Added Successfully!');
                }
            }
        }
        return back();
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

If product_image column in excel has URL of image then you need to install Laravel Image Intervention Package:
http://image.intervention.io/
or
https://github.com/Intervention/image

After install, try this code for store images from URL in Local Laravel Storage and save the path in Database:

```
public function excelupload()
    {

        if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
            $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            })->get();
            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    dd($value);

                        $file = $value->product_image;
                        if ($file) 
                        {
                            $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                               $main_image = Image::make(file_get_contents($file))->widen(860, function ($constraint) {
                                 $constraint->upsize();
                               });
                               $dir = 'photos/';
                               $path = uniqid().'.jpg';
                               $main_image->encode();
                               Storage::put($dir.$path, (string)$main_image);

                               $product_image = $path;
                        }else{
                            $product_image = null;
                        }

                    $insert[] = [
                                    'product_name' => $value->product_name, 
                                    'cataloge_number' => $value->cataloge_number, 
                                    'cas_number' => $value->cas_number, 
                                    // 'product_image' => $value->product_image, 
                                    'product_image' => $product_image,
                                    'chemical_name' => $value->chemical_name , 
                                    'synonyms' => $value->synonyms , 
                                    'molecular_formula' => $value->molecular_formula, 
                                    'molecular_mass' => $value->molecular_mass, 
                                    'product_stock' => $value->product_stock
                                ];
                }
                if(!empty($insert)){

                    DB::table('products')->insert($insert);

                   return redirect('admin/product')->with('message', 'New Product Added Successfully!');
                }
            }
        }
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: image do not inserting in database.

Comment: product_image column have image URL ??

Comment: Sure, kindly share.

Comment: return $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();

Comment: run this code and share Array/Json. I want to know what is showing product_image field in Exel

Comment: {
product_name: "xyz",
cataloge_number: "45456dsf",
cas_number: "sdfsdfdsf",
product_image: null,
chemical_name: "sdfdsfdsf",
synonyms: "fdsfds",
molecular_formula: "dsfds",
molecular_mass: "dfdsfds",
product_stock: "dsfdsfds"
}

Comment: You need to convert the images into URLs in excel.

Comment: Maybe there has any command in Excel to covert image obj. into URLs or code.

Comment: So, you need to decode the images or convert them into URLs.

Comment: following links help you:

Comment: http://www.walkswithme.net/reading-images-from-excel-sheet-using-phpexcel